# string index out of bounds leads to build not being finished

Tags: android-studio, android-xml, stringindexoutofbounds

In my android studio I'm not able to see my xml editor preview, everytime I try to see the window it displays this message: "*waiting for build to finish*".
I suspect it to be the cause of a **String index out of bounds exeption** I'm having everytime I start up my android studio.

**String index out of bounds exeption**:

```
String index out of range: 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
```

full stacktrace:

https://pastebin.com/t0XnjTFL

also autocompletion is somehow disabled (even tough it is turned on) in my xml editor.

Comment: I have the same problem in an old project. Did you resolved?